# what does the character say in this video?

Tags: translation, verbs

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcR7Vr5Miv4&t=1m38s

What I hear is something similar to "saa ute koi". The phrase is translated as "hit me!" . I know ute is "shoot!" I guess here it could be "hit me" and that koi is "come!" but it doesnt make sense to me that 2 verbs in imperative form are concantenated together? Besides what is that sound at the begining I hear similar to "saa" . What is the character saying exactly I might be completely confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He says 「さあ、打って{うって}こい！」'Saa, utte koi!' This is the imperative of 'utte kuru', 'come and hit someone'. 'Saa' is something said before a command or request.

Comment: so it was exactly what I hear, happy to at least hear right. What is the saa for? emphasis?

Comment: @Pablo You heard 'ute koi'. It was actually 'utte koi'. But yes, 'saa' is for emphasis.

Comment: @Pablo さあ is an interjection. It's like "Hey" or "Come on" here.